# What's the difference between MMC enterprise and trial?

Tags: mule

I understand that Mule Management Console (mmc) only available for the enterprise edition. However, when I start mmc.zip, I get that information

"This Mule ESB Enterprise with Mule Management Console (MMC) bundle is appropriate for use only as an evaluation tool and is not considered production-ready.

To use MMC for stress testing or in a production environment, download the .war file from MuleSoft's customer portal and deploy the MMC on an application server, such as Tomcat. Please contact the MuleSoft Support Team with any questions about downloading and deploying Mule Management Console."

I wonder what is the difference between those two editions. I mean, not only what they (Mule Soft) mention above, I want to know more about mmc product version, which more functions it provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle has MMC deployed on Mule, with Derby persistence.

In production, you need to deploy MMC on a JavaEE container with external DB persistence.